# How to import my database In mysql workbench?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have Created Database using MySQL. its connect to my site file. now i have to move my site my server.how to connect my database  server ?

```
Database Name: mysql_24172_abacu 
 Database Server: **********
 Database User: abacu 
Database Password: *********
```

how to connect this config file to server in MySQL workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't import anything into MySQL Workbench. It's a client program that connects to a server and works with that (management, data querying + manipulation, user management etc.). If you want to move your data from one server to a different machine try the migration feature which can easily do a MySQL -> MySQL migration, including version upgrades.